# How can I get my companion to not throw grenades at the mosquitos?

Tags: fallout-4

On Fallout 4 (on PC) I've given my companion (Hancock) my stash of fragmentation grenades. Since he's got a shotgun, and I've got a sword, I figure he's the better of us to be chucking them. I've taken a level in the 'Inspirational' perk so I don't have to be worried about him injuring me by tossing them too close.

But now my problem is that he goes for the grenades first instead of his shotgun. Just now we were hiking to a settlement and came across a swarm of bloodbugs. I drew my sword and attacked them -- and Hancock threw a grenade.

I mean, seriously. I like explosions as much as the next gal, but they're just glorified mosquitos the size of a large dog. **Is there some way to get him to prefer his gun to the grenades?** Is it somehow related to the weapon I've given him? He's got a shotgun, which means he gets two shots and then has a slow reload -- I don't recall having this problem when I had him equipped with a plasma rifle in another save game.

Comment: Do not give explosive weapons to your companions.  Do not give full automatic weapons to companions.  Give them one shot mid to long range weapons.  I had Strong fire a full explosive minigun clip at me once.  It stripped my power armor to red and put me at 30hp in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: I took the inspirational perk. I do not take damage from companions, including the grenades. Learned that the hard way and now I don't give them grenades until I take at least one level of that perk.. ;)

Comment: has anyone hit a mosquito/flying insect with a grenade?  I want to see that happen in game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the base AI in this game is pretty dumb. The only real consideration it makes is "MOAR DAMAGE MEANS BETTERER".

The good thing about it - no one is more accurate with grenades than AI. The bad thing about it - It doesn't matter if it's a mosquito or a Super Mutant Behemoth - moar damage means betterer.

There are mods out the that can help stem the flow of grenade spam, like [this one](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/20720/?tab=description), which simply depletes their ammo for grenades, but that doesn't really help your situation.

The only other suggestion I can provide is give him a gun that deals more damage than your average grenade, but since they don't have an "armory", per se, they'll then switch from solely using the grenades, to solely using the other weapon.

Comment: That's... Inconvenient. Is there some sort of middle ground using vanilla wherein they'll use both to some extent?

Comment: @Roddy how about only giving them grenades when you are planning an encounter, such as fighting your way into the Water treatment plant? That way any 'surprise' encounters including blood bugs they simply don't have any to throw?